# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i have this error in selenium python

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[24]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/button[1]"}
```

i want the element with this xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[24]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/button[1]").click()
```

if doesn't exist, then click other element with other xpath like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[24]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/button[2]").click()
```

everything is clear if element 1 doesn't exists to click, click to element 2

how can I do this in selenium python

thanks

Comment: Add html code to your question

Comment: add html code code, or share the web page link for a proper solution

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchElementException` generally occurs because of one the below reasons

- Element locator is incorrect
- Element is not rendered
- Page is not rendered or loaded
- Element is inside a frame

You can have a look, do a debug and based on that write your code. :)

Comment: yes i know some time element A don't be rendered and when if this element is don't exists click to element B

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact solution, but this is the idea

```
if elem1.is_displayed():
    elem1.click()
else:
    elem2.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you using `time.sleep(10)` and a `nested try block` to catch your errors while it accomplishes what you want to do. For example:

```
time.sleep(10)

try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[24]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/button[1]").click()
except:
    print("button1 could not be found... Now trying to retreive button2")

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[24]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/button[2]").click()
    except:
        print("button1 nor button2 were not found...")
```

Note that the `time.sleep(10)` delays your code from executing anything after this line for 10 seconds, and this allows the page to load properly for elements to be located easier.